# Why does Apache CXF WS-Security implementation ignore GET requests

Tags: cxf, ws-security

I'm exposing a service as a SOAP Webservice using [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) 2.4.1.
I'm using CXF's [WS-Security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html) implementation to implement a custom authentication and authorization.

Everything is being wired with Spring.

My CallbackHandler is being properly called upon a normal SOAP request.
But when a request comes from a simple GET request, like calling the service from a browser with the url below, my handler is not called.

```
http://localhost:8080/ws/customerService/findById?id=1
```

Checking [CXF's WS-Security code](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/cxf/trunk/rt/ws/security/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ws/security/wss4j/WSS4JInInterceptor.java?r=1167214#to173) it is ignoring GET requests completely (code below).
Why?

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage msg) throws Fault {
    if (msg.containsKey(SECURITY_PROCESSED) || isGET(msg)) {
        return;
    }
   ...
 }
```